# Websocket SignalR does not start

Tags: websocket, signalr

I just deployed a MVC web app to my windows server 2012. It has Windows 8 and IIS v8 installed. The application uses SignalR, and I would like to use websockets, but it gives errors.

In every browser (chrome ff, ie) the error is the same:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - https://domain.com/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=wiiR333%2BkbKu0Ex2SPZLE9W9X6eAm5lBssbjXbqCvl0QpjAiGtHkn1xiIQHYGi3O4DDLIv7whTahVb8Ll5kfwjnrzaZaDYCApWj5aWm6d1cZzxH89K%2BouHziBH7dCt9I&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22charthub%22%7D%5D&tid=8"
```

The detailed error message would be:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Not a valid web socket request.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport.AcceptWebSocketRequest(Func`2 callback)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(HostContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ProcessRequest(HostContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I asked in the SignalR Jabbr chat what the error would be and they told me something is blocking the connections. I checked, and both TCP port 80 and port 443 are listening.

The IIS trust level is `Full (internal)` and we're not using loadbalancing. The `Websockets protocol` is installed.

What could be wrong?

Comment: do other transport types work? how are you setting up the connection? is there a proxy between client and server?

Comment: We figured out that it is Sophos that is in a way blocking the websocket protocol. Still trying to look for the solution, but it has nothing to do with SignalR